# Position-based replacement of block of text if string is matched in the same line

Tags: bash, awk, position, replace

I have two sets of PDB files (this is a standard format which cannot be modified). First set is like:

```
ATOM     18  C33 Q58 d  91     -25.677   3.886 -30.044  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     19  C34 Q58 d  91     -24.704   4.881 -29.447  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     20  C35 Q58 d  91     -23.382   4.873 -30.182  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     21  C8  Q58 d  91     -20.295  11.484 -33.616  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     22  C7  Q58 d  91     -19.198  12.305 -33.381  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM     23  C3  Q58 d  91     -18.213  12.498 -34.383  1.00  0.00           C
```

And the second one goes:

```
HETATM 2686  C7  589 A   1     -19.344  12.177 -33.319  1.00 25.88           C  
HETATM 2687  C8  589 A   1     -20.388  11.319 -33.511  1.00 26.31           C  
HETATM 2688  C9  589 A   1     -20.364  10.691 -34.747  1.00 26.14           C  
HETATM 2689  C10 589 A   1     -19.402  10.845 -35.729  1.00 26.34           C  
HETATM 2690  N11 589 A   1     -21.334  11.123 -32.604  1.00 26.22           N  
HETATM 2691  C12 589 A   1     -21.713   9.967 -32.081  1.00 25.65           C
```

Each column is separated by a variable number of spaces so that its contents occupy a specific positional range.

Columns 7-9 represent x,y,z coordinates in the Cartesian space. I would like to replace the coordinates of file 2 with coordinates from file 1 for all column 3 (atom type) matches.

For instance, in the example, the output file 2 would be:

```
HETATM 2686  C7  589 A   1     -19.198  12.305 -33.381  1.00 25.88           C  
HETATM 2687  C8  589 A   1     -20.295  11.484 -33.616  1.00 26.31           C  
HETATM 2688  C9  589 A   1     -20.364  10.691 -34.747  1.00 26.14           C  
HETATM 2689  C10 589 A   1     -19.402  10.845 -35.729  1.00 26.34           C  
HETATM 2690  N11 589 A   1     -21.334  11.123 -32.604  1.00 26.22           N  
HETATM 2691  C12 589 A   1     -21.713   9.967 -32.081  1.00 25.65           C
```

Please, note how the coordinates have changed for the first two lines (atoms C7 and C8).

I have tried awk, but it seems too delimiter-dependent, which is not good in this example. Column 3 (atom type) is always at positions 14-16, whereas the 3 coordinate columns span from 32 to 54.

NOTE: In certain cases, certain columns may be merged. For instance, in this example columns 5 and 6 and merged (this can also happen with columns 1 and 2):

```
HETATM 2804  PG  ANP A1001      23.808  17.953  28.350  1.00 52.23           P
```

My SOLUTION this far (slow, but works):

```
while read line ; do
atom=$(echo "$line" | cut -c13-16)
coord=$(grep -i "$atom" ${ligand}_${chain}_dock.tmp | cut -c32-54)
echo "$line" | sed -r "s/^(.{31})(.{23})/\1${coord}/" >> ${ligand}_${chain}_dock.pdb
done < ${ligand}_${chain}_ref.pdb
```

Comment: What do you want to do when field 3 does not match?

Comment: Nothing. Just keep the original coordinates. However, there should always be a match. Please, just keep in mind that column 1 can be merged to column 2 and column 4 can be merged to column 5 in certain files.

Comment: The exact width of each field would be helpful.

Comment: This would be so much simpler if `join(1)` could be taught about fixed width fields.

Comment: Your solution, FYI, will fail to keep the trailing whitespace at the end of each line. I presume this was important for the format.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that, Sorpigal. Yet, the trailing white-spaces  seem to be mostly irrelevant in this case (and I guess that in general). In any case, they can be easily added. if required.

Answer (score 3):

I probably choose a stupid way to solve it: playing with printf statement. however it works for your example.

command:

```
 awk -F' *' 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$7;b[$3]=$8;c[$3]=$9;next;}\
{if($3 in a)printf "%s %s  %-3s %s %s %3s %11s %7s %7s %5s %s %11s\n",\
        $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,a[$3],b[$3],c[$3],$10,$11,$12; else print $0}' file1 file2
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  awk -F' *' 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$7;b[$3]=$8;c[$3]=$9;next;}
{if($3 in a)printf "%s %s  %-3s %s %s %3s %11s %7s %7s %5s %s %11s\n",
        $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,a[$3],b[$3],c[$3],$10,$11,$12; else print $0}' file1 file2
HETATM 2686  C7  589 A   1     -19.198  12.305 -33.381  1.00 25.88           C
HETATM 2687  C8  589 A   1     -20.295  11.484 -33.616  1.00 26.31           C
HETATM 2688  C9  589 A   1     -20.364  10.691 -34.747  1.00 26.14           C  
HETATM 2689  C10 589 A   1     -19.402  10.845 -35.729  1.00 26.34           C  
HETATM 2690  N11 589 A   1     -21.334  11.123 -32.604  1.00 26.22           N  
HETATM 2691  C12 589 A   1     -21.713   9.967 -32.081  1.00 25.65           C
```

Comment: +1. You don't need the end-of-line backslashes, nor do you need to explicitly `print $0` -- simply `print`. The default field separator is "whitespace", so you don't need to use `-F`.

Comment: This solution has a problem, which is why I usually have troubles with awk and PDB files. Sometimes columns are merged. This is typically the case when column 2 value is larger than 99999 or column 4 value is larger than 999 or 9999, as, for instance: HETATM 2804  PG  ANP A1001      23.808  17.953  28.350  1.00 52.23           P

Comment: That is why I need a method that is strictly position-dependent and not delimiter-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

I took a guess at the correct field widths, but this should work if they're adjusted correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file1="$1"
file2="$2"

fw=(7 6 4 4 4 6 9 7 9 5 16 4)

while IFS= read -r -a f2_line ; do
    let pos=0
    f2_fields=()
    for width in "${fw[@]}" ; do
            f2_fields=("${f2_fields[@]}" "${f2_line:${pos}:${width}}")
            let pos+=width
    done

    printf '%s' "${f2_fields[@]:0:6}"
    orig=1
    while IFS= read -r -a f1_line ; do
            let pos=0
            f1_fields=()
            for width in "${fw[@]}" ; do
                    f1_fields=("${f1_fields[@]}" "${f1_line:${pos}:${width}}")
                    let pos+=width
            done
            if [ "${f1_fields[2]}" = "${f2_fields[2]}" ] ; then
                    orig=
                    printf '%s' "${f1_fields[@]:6:3}"
                    break
            fi
    done < "$file1"
    if [ ! -z "$orig" ] ; then
            printf '%s' "${f2_fields[@]:6:3}"
    fi
    printf '%s' "${f2_fields[@]:9}"
    printf '\n'
done < "$file2"
```

It is, of course, not very efficient.

EDIT: Oops, had to s/5/6/ on line 14. Works now.

Answer (score 0):

This would work too. Instead of printing each column, we set the OFS variable to "\t".

**UPDATE:** Added few more spaces next to tab in the OFS variable. This gives your output enough spacing between each other.

```
[jaypal:~/Temp]  awk -v OFS="\t    " 'NR==FNR{a[$3]=$7;b[$3]=$8;c[$3]=$9;next} ($3 in a) {$7=a[$3];$8=b[$3];$9=c[$3];print $0;next} {$1=$1}1' file1 file2
HETATM      2686        C7      589     A       1       -19.198     12.305      -33.381     1.00        25.88       C
HETATM      2687        C8      589     A       1       -20.295     11.484      -33.616     1.00        26.31       C
HETATM      2688        C9      589     A       1       -20.364     10.691      -34.747     1.00        26.14       C
HETATM      2689        C10     589     A       1       -19.402     10.845      -35.729     1.00        26.34       C
HETATM      2690        N11     589     A       1       -21.334     11.123      -32.604     1.00        26.22       N
HETATM      2691        C12     589     A       1       -21.713     9.967       -32.081     1.00        25.65       C
```